# Align sub label below the main label

Tags: html, css

I have the following code where checkbox with labels related stuff is messed up as shown below:

```css
/* CSS */

div.settings {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    grid-gap:5px;
}
div.settings label       { text-align:right; }
div.settings label:after { content: ":"; }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="settings">
    <label>Label #1</label>
    <input type="text" />

    <label>Long Label #2</label>
    <span>Display content</span>

    <label>Label #3</label>
    <input type="text" />
    
     <label><input id="topList" name="list" type="checkbox" >Main Label</label>
    <label><input id="list1" name="list" type="checkbox" >First Sub Label</label>
    <label><input id="list2" name="list" type="checkbox" >Second Sub Label</label>
    <label><input id="list3" name="list" type="checkbox" >Third Sub Label</label>
    
</div>
```

I want the checkbox related stuff to be displayed like this:
[image]

How should I proceed?

Comment: What are your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the desired indentation in child checkboxes, you need to know their size and indentation in advance. In the example below, I put these dimensions into a css variables:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  --checkbox-size: 16px;
  --checkbox-margin-right: 8px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style :none;
}

ul [type="checkbox"] {
  width: var(--checkbox-size);
  height: var(--checkbox-size);
  margin-right: var(--checkbox-margin-right);
}

ul label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul ul {
  margin-left: calc( var(--checkbox-size) + var(--checkbox-margin-right) );
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label><input type="checkbox">checkbox</label>
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox">checkbox</label></li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox">checkbox</label>
        <ul>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox">checkbox</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox">checkbox</label></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```